# How can insert parameter value into database by using querydsl?

Tags: sql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

```
 @Override
    @Transactional
    public void saveBody(String body) {
       var entityPath = new QWord("word");
       var query = new JPAQuery<>(this.entityManager);
       JPAQueryFactory jpaQueryFactory = new JPAQueryFactory(this.entityManager);
       jpaQueryFactory.insert(entityPath).set(entityPath.body, body).execute();    
    }
```

What is wrong with code ?

> error: Caused by: org.hibernate.query.SemanticException: A query
> exception occurred [insert into Word (body) word.body = ?1]

I got this

> error : Caused by: org.hibernate.query.SemanticException: A query
> exception occurred [insert into Word (body) word.body = ?1]

Answer (score 0):

It does not look to be the proper way of creating an entity.

The proper way would be something like:

```
SQLInsertClause insertClause = new SQLInsertClause(connection, SQLTemplates.DEFAULT, entityPath)
    .set(entityPath.body, body)
    .execute();
```

References: [DslQuery insert](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/querydsl-examples/src/master/#markdown-header-a-simple-insert)

I think it is easier to create the entity using a [JPA repository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html) itself.

JPA repository for managing entities of `Word`.

```
// assuming the ID of the entity Word is Long
public interface WordRepository extends JpaRepository<Word, Long> {
}
```

In your service layer, autowired the repository.

```
@Autowired
private WordRepository wordRepository;
```

Then you can use it to save your new entities or update them as well.

```
Word word = new Word();
word.setBody(body)

wordRepository.save(word);
```

Comment: How could create my query using jpg ?   jpaQueryFactory.insert(entityPath).set(entityPath.body, body).execute();

Comment: I have updated the answer with an example. QueryDsl is mostly used for creating complex queries, it provides a peace of mind for type safety. For most queries, the `JpaRepository` should be enough.